# micropython ds18x20 wrong rom/address/serial

Tags: esp32, micropython

I have  ESP23 dev kit with micropython firmware esp32-idf3-20200329-v1.12-317-g688323307. 
I also have ds18b20 waterproof sensor. [datasheet link](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf)

I wrote this code for it:

```
import time, onewire, ds18x20
import machine

from machine import Pin

ds_pin=Pin(19)
ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))

roms = ds_sensor.scan()

for rom in roms:
    print(rom)
```

It returns tis info:

```
[bytearray(b'(\xbcN6\x14\x19\x01\xba')]
```

Before reading temp data from sensor, we first need to use the scan() function to scan for DS18B20 sensors. The addresses found are saved on the roms variable (the roms variable is of type list). scan() function sends request and sensor returns its unique 64-bit serial code.

[I used manual here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/micropython-ds18b20-esp32-esp8266/)

Today I bought two more ds18x20 waterproof sensors (I don’t know what type of sensor - ds18a20/ds18b20 or else - are they, ‘cause eager chinese manufacturers sealed sensors inside metal bullet too good, so I can’t just look inside).
I tried to run the same code with them, but it returned the following:

```
bytearray(b'(\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\xfc\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\xf8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\xf0\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\xd0\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\xf6\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\xe6\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\xc6\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86\xf9\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xff\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xfe\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xfa\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xf2\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xe2\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\xff\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\xfd\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\xf9\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\xf1\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\xe1\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\xc1\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x81\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\xff\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\xfb\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\xf3\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\xe3\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\xc3\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\x83\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\x03\xff')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\x03\xfe')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\x03\xfc')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\x03\xdc')
bytearray(b'(\x90\x86y\xa2\x01\x03\\')
```

When I try to read temperature using this values it returns ‘CRC error’.

What can be done? Is the problem with code, or the sensors are failed somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect one sensor at a time when you do the scan.
2. You haven't shared how you're wired the DS18x20 sensor. Make sure its positive power connection is to 3.3V not 5V.
3. Make sure you've connected a resistor (4.7K should be good) between the data pin of the sensor and 3.3V. OneWire devices absolutely won't work reliably without this resistor - you might see the kind of problem you're seeing.

If you're sure it's wired correctly the next step would be to try it with different firmware, for instance a Dallas one-wire scanner using the Arduino Core. That would eliminate the possibility of problems with the library you're using and MicroPython.

Comment: 1. check. 2. check. sensor wired in normal mode (not parasite). 3. I thought about this. the first sensor work with out pull up resistor. But China so diffrent China... I try to use inner pull up mode (Pin.PULL_UP) but it didn't help.  Will go to understand how working arduino)))

Answer (score 0):

looks like fake sensor

[How to tell original from fake DS18B20 temperature sensors](https://github.com/cpetrich/counterfeit_DS18B20)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i'm a fool))
Yes. One 4.7K pull up resistor and it's alive! IT'S ALIVE!!
aaaand whats'up doc? 
then we use internal PULL_UP mode we pull up signal only for ESP. 
BUT! DS18B20 is microchip too. And the wire for little DS18B20 is like giant radio aerial. 
Maybe in my first sensor this problem was solved on hard level.